# Python Comand Line Debugging and Inheritance

Tags: python-2.7, debugging

I am working on some legacy Python 2.6.5 code and am limited to break points and command line tools to debug. I'm using

```
dir(obj)
```

to explore what existing attributes exist in live object. The dir I am using does not disambiguate from which class particular attributes come. I am interested in determining the association between the listed attributes and in which class I can find the an attribute's source code.

Are there other standard python 2.6.5 object query command line tools?

```
class MainClass(InheritClass1, 
                InheritClass2,
                InheritClass3,
                InheritClass5):

    def _doSomething(self, *args, **kwargs):
        x = self.MethodOne()         
        y = x * 100
```

If a breakpoint is placed at the line x = self.MethodOne() and I used

```
dir(self)
```

from a debug command prompt I'd like to see from which class the MethodOne function is inherited.

Comment: Have you considered just looking at the code? Searching for `def MethodOne(` would be a good start.

Comment: Thank you and yes, of course, I can grep through the code as well. But I'm looking to supplement my toolkit if there is something available.